# Get-ADUser - Filter child OU's and users where surname is empty

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

I am trying to run a command where I get all active directory users in the parent OU (Users) and filter out the child OU's (Admin accounts, service accounts, disabled accounts) as well as filter out any user account that does not have a surname in the surname field.

At the moment I have

```
Get-ADUser -Filter{enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local' | Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$Disabled" } | Where {$_.Surname -notlike "$Null"} | select samAccountName
```

When I add another child OU after 'Disabled' there is an error

`Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Where'.`

Please may someone advise on how to filter out additional child OU's?

Comment: Are you sure your code looks exactly like the one pasted here? Looking at it there doesnt seem a syntax issue that would cause the error you've provided

Answer (score 0):

Good day Smoore

The problem is you are using multiple **Where-object** cmdlets but you only need one and separate them using **()** and adding the -and option, also to refer to **$null** value you don't need to use the **""** marks

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local" | Where-Object {($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*,$Disabled*") -and ($_.Surname -notlike $Null)} | select samAccountName
```

With this options you should be able to get all the users you want

Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi jjquintero245. Thanks so much for your kind effort and reply. This has really helped me. My additional question is how do I add another child OU to my list of child OU's to ignore? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Smoore, you can keep adding -and ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "Another_OU") inside of the {}

Comment: Hi, thank you! This works. Lastly, do you know how I can add a user to a security group if they their last name is not null? Thanks!

Comment: You can add the output of the first command to a variable and add them to the group using "IF"

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex `-notmatch` so it would be possible to combine all OU Distinguished names in just one variable.

Something like this:

```
$Admins   = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local'
$Service  = 'OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local'
$Disabled = 'OU=DisabledUsers,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local'

# build a regex string from the above OU DistinguishedNames
$Exclude = '({0}|{1}|{2})$' -f [regex]::Escape($Admins), [regex]::Escape($Service), [regex]::Escape($Disabled)

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local' | 
Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Surname) -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $Exclude } | 
Select-Object SamAccountName
```

---

As per your comment:

```
$Admins   = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local'
$Service  = 'OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local'
$Disabled = 'OU=DisabledUsers,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local'

# the group you want to add the users to
$TargetGroup = 'Company Team'

# build a regex string from the above OU DistinguishedNames
$Exclude = '({0}|{1}|{2})$' -f [regex]::Escape($Admins), [regex]::Escape($Service), [regex]::Escape($Disabled)

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=CompanyName,DC=local' | 
         Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Surname) -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $Exclude }

# get the AD group as object
$GroupObject = Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq '$TargetGroup'"

# now add these users that have Surnames to the security group  all in one go
try {
    Write-Host "Adding $(@($users).Count) users to group $TargetGroup"
    $GroupObject | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $users -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}

# or if you prefer loop through the users and add each one individually then use this instead
# foreach ($user in $users) {
    # try {
        # Write-Host "Adding user $($users.Name) to group $TargetGroup"
        # $GroupObject | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $user -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
    # }
    # catch {
        # Write-Warning "Error adding user $($users.Name) to group $($TargetGroup): $($_.Exception.Message)"
    # }
# }
```

Comment: Hi Theo. Thank you for this. Do you know how I can add a user to a security group if they their last name is not null? Thanks!

Comment: @Smoore Please see my edit. BTW. Being new to the platform, may I point you to see the [tour], where amongst other interesting stuff you can read how to mark a question 'done' if an answer solves your problem.