# Get-ADUser - Filter child OU's and users where surname is empty then add to mail-enabled security group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I posted 4 days ago and the community have been really helpful! I can now look for users in a specific parent OU who have a last name.

My second step that I am trying to do is to now **add those users who have a last name and are in the parent OU to a mail enabled security group**. After some googling I found a piece of script that allows users to be added to such, but I need to edit to to specify my requirements. I thought I had tried to do this but it ended up still searching through the child OUs and adding those without a last name so I must have something wrong or jumbled.

My current script is

```
$Admin_Accounts   = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
$Service_Accounts  = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
$Disabled = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
$Test_PowerPoint_GPO = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'

$Exclude = '({0}|{1}|{2})$' -f \[regex\]::Escape($Admin_Accounts), \[regex\]::Escape($Service_Accounts), \[regex\]::Escape($Disabled), \[regex\]::Escape($Test_PowerPoint_GPO)

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local' |
Where-Object { !\[string\]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Surname) -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $Exclude } |
Select-Object SamAccountName

$TargetGroup = “Company Team“
$TargetOU = “OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=Company,DC=local“
$Exclude = '({0}|{1}|{2})$' -f \[regex\]::Escape($Admin_Accounts), \[regex\]::Escape($Service_Accounts), \[regex\]::Escape($Disabled), \[regex\]::Escape($Test_PowerPoint_GPO)
$UserAccounts = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' | ?{$_.DistinguishedName -like “_*$TargetOU*” -and $.Enabled -eq “True”}
Where-Object { !\[string\]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Surname) -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $Exclude } |
Select-Object SamAccountName
ForEach($User in $UserAccounts)
{
$UsersName = $User.Name
\#Check for group membership
$Membership = Get-ADGroup $TargetGroup | Get-ADGroupMember | ?{$\_.Name -eq $UsersName}
if(!$Membership)
{
“Adding $UsersName to $TargetGroup”
Get-ADGroup $TargetGroup | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $User -Verbose
}
}
```

I tried to add pieces of script to specify my requirements

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you posted a new question about this. I just answered based on your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74563728/9898643)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your script is way more complex than it needs to be:

```
$Admin_Accounts   = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
$Service_Accounts  = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
$Disabled = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
$Test_PowerPoint_GPO = 'OU=Administrators,OU=Company,DC=CompanyDC,DC=local'
# Create regex matching list
[regex]$Exclude = "$Admin_Accounts|$Service_Accounts|$Disabled|$Test_PowerPoint_GPO"

$UserAccounts = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' | Where-Object {
    $_.DistinguishedName -like “_*$TargetOU*”
} | Where-Object {
        ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Surname) -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $Exclude
    } | Select-Object SamAccountName
```